# Create cryptographic signature of less than 1024 bits

Tags: .net, qr-code, digital-signature

I need to sign a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qr_code) and I tried using some standard .Net code to create a cryptographic signature:

```
var privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PrivateKey;
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( payload );
var signature = privateKey.SignData( data, new SHA1Managed() );
```

This works but the signature is 1024 bits long - too much for the QR code I want to create.

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate a shorter signature, e.g. 512 bits?

Alternatively, is there a standard for signing QR codes?

Comment: Is there a reason, preventing you from using DSA instead of RSA?

Comment: I simply need to sign the QR Code so that it can't be faked. Any signing algorithm that produces a short enough hash and is widely implemented, including in .Net, would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The signature will be the same length as the modulus for the keys you are using. If you are not specifying the modulus when creating the certificate it will default to 1024 bits. You can change the length to 512 and then the resulting signature will be 512 bits.

To change the modulus when creating the certificate use the [RSAParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) struct.

Comment: It's a 2048 bit key, yet the signature is 1024 bits - not the same length.

Comment: Note that just dropping key size might be a bad idea; [512 bit RSA keys were being factored 12 years ago](https://blog.perfect-privacy.com/2010/01/09/rsa-768-bit-key-broken-after-2½-years-of-brute-force-factoring/).

Comment: @sarnold: True. My answer in this case was not 100% correct. The length of the signature does not correlate to the length of the key but rather the length of the modulus. So it is not necessary to change the keysize.